# Getting error when using functions in pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am adding a formula in a transformation in **kettle**. In the properties of that formula, when I click on formula textfield, I get an error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=''] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-mozilla-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
/home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3740.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Can't load library: /home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.libformula.ui.editor.LibFormulaEditor.<init>(LibFormulaEditor.java:198)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.formula.FormulaDialog$3.widgetSelected(FormulaDialog.java:219)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.widget.TableView.editText(TableView.java:1940)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.widget.TableView.edit(TableView.java:1895)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.widget.TableView.edit(TableView.java:1867)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.widget.TableView.editSelected(TableView.java:1326)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.widget.TableView.access$3000(TableView.java:107)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.widget.TableView$26.mouseDown(TableView.java:949)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.formula.FormulaDialog.open(FormulaDialog.java:282)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:136)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:7835)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:2749)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1221)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7044)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8304)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:580)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-mozilla-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
/home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3740.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Can't load library: /home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
... 35 more
```

When I am checking `/home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/` it has the file `libswt-mozilla-gtk-3740.so`

Kindly help me with the solution

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues that can prevent this functionality to work. 
The root cause is that Pentaho uses SWT functionality that requires one of two browsers that installed in the operating system. Refer to this faq (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux).
In my case, we must choose whether we want to use WebKitGTK (webkit) or Mozilla Firefox (mozilla) by adding a VM option to the java command line :

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

In my system, Ubuntu 14.04, the webkit browser causes an error in libsoup, so I need to set this to mozilla. For reference see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501 for libsoup error in Eclipse which also uses SWT, similar to Pentaho.

Then, we need mozilla firefox to be present in the system, and also the mozilla XUL runner library.  Install firefox first :

`apt-get install firefox`

Install XUL runner 1.9.2 because 2.0.0 or later is said to be incompatible (see http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-8730).

`wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/2012/03/2012-03-02-03-32-11-mozilla-1.9.2/xulrunner-1.9.2.28pre.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2`

`tar -xjf xulrunner-1.9.2.28pre.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2`

`mv xulrunner /opt/xulrunner-1.9.2`

Configure the xulrunner path using this VM option :

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner-1.9.2`

We also need to configure LD_LIBRARY_PATH and MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to point to the xulrunner :

`MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/opt/xulrunner-1.9.2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

The final setting in spoon.sh is :

(spoon.sh, about line 13)

`MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/opt/xulrunner-1.9.2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

(spoon.sh, about line 184)
`if [ -z "$PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS" ]; then
    PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner-1.9.2"
fi`

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this issue by replacing the SWT jar and SWT-GTK jar in Kettle's libswt folder.

Diethard Steiner described the simple process on his blog, using the JAR files from Eclipse:

http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2015/06/07/Fixing-PDI-GLib-CRITICAL.html

This way you don't have to mess with start script; but keep in mind that the change will be overwritten by an update, too.